# Old notations in an article

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am reading an old article on group theory. During the proof of one of the theorem there is a statement as follows: "**there is an isomorphism
of $U$ onto $V$ which maps $G$ qua subgroup of $U$ identically onto $G$ qua sub
group of $V$",** I do not understand what they mean by **"qua"**

Comment: "Considered as a", or "in its capacity as".  This isn't old notation; "qua" is an English word.

Comment: The "qua" is Latin for "as", meaning, as @saulspatz notes, "considered as". Using such Latin words was much more common in scholarly English 50 (or more) years ago than it is today, especially when English is serving a more international role.

Comment: Typically I would expect to see a Latin abbreviation such as this italicized, marking it as a non-English word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Qua](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/qua) : in the capacity or character of.

It's a conjunction. A re-writing of the sentence could be:

> There is an isomorphism of $U$ onto $V$ which maps $G$, acting as a subgroup of $U$, identically onto $G$, acting as a subgroup of $V$.